# Display Order details before downloads on WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I have a customer order email with this hook

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

In this hook we have the email-downloads content which gets loaded first and then the email-order-details. I need to get the email-order-details first and the downloads below but can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you look to [`WC_Emails` constructor function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L186-L212) you will see those 2 related code lines:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $this, 'order_downloads' ), 10, 4 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $this, 'order_details' ), 10, 4 );
```

Based on that code, the following hooked function will set the display of the **order downloads** section after the **order details**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'wc_email_order_details_action_callback', 1 );
function wc_email_order_details_action_callback() {

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( WC()->mailer, 'order_downloads' ), 10 );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( WC()->mailer, 'order_downloads' ), 11, 4 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.